# How can I detect link in the selection?

Tags: javascript, dom

If a user select text which are in an "a" tag I have to remove it. If a link larger than div it carets on new lines and when I start to select with middle I get only text. So how I can attain that purpose and get the link effectively?

```js
  function GetSelectedText () {
  
   if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
         if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
            }
            html = container.innerHTML;
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
        }
    }
    alert(html);
  }
```

```css
.textField 
{
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onmouseup="GetSelectedText ()">
<div class="textField">Carnotaurus, a large theropod dinosaur, lived during the Late Cretaceous period. Known from a single well-preserved skeleton found in Argentina, it is a member of the Abelisauridae family<a href="#">and one of the best-understood theropods from the Southern Hemisphere. Carnotaurus (derived from Latin for "meat-eating bull") had thick horns above the eyes, and a very deep skull on a muscular neck.</a>t was a lightly built, bipedal predator, 8 to 9 m (26.2 to 29.5 ft) long, weighing at least 1.35 metric tons (1.49 short tons). It had small, vestigial forelimbs and long and slender hindlimbs. Preserved skin impressions show a mosaic of small scales interrupted by large bumps that lined the sides of the animal. </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(container.getElementsByTagName('a').length)` ?

Comment: No, I need to define if My selection is a link.

Comment: didn't I understand you ? -  https://jsfiddle.net/Lvotu1y4/

Comment: @splash58, if you will select only "Southern" or something else with right side you will get "no". Now I get understand what I need to do, I have <div id="IdElement"> here text, links, br, i and etc tags </div> <div id="NextIdEnd">NothingItsJustABoundaryPoint</div>. I have to create range object and set start and end, then every time after selection the function has to remove previous selection and I have not to be able to select link. https://jsfiddle.net/dmfranklin/zbdqzhn6/

Comment: it does nothing on the link

Comment: @splash58, it's because the first part of script is not working, try this https://jsfiddle.net/dmfranklin/qg1cp6qt/